# Can I use a VLAN-unaware switch in a hierarchical switch topology?

Tags: switch, vlan

I have the Following VLANs:

1. Systems
2. Logistics
3. Marketing

I need that:

- All VLANs can go out to the Internet
- Logistics and Marketing can access servers on the Systems VLAN
- Logistics and Marketing cannot see with each other

So I've made the following schema:

[image]

- Router at the top should route between VLANs
- Switch immediately connected to the router is VLAN-unaware
- The 3 switches below are VLAN-aware

Is it right?

Comment: you mean "The 3 switches below are vlan *un*aware". From what you say all your switches are vlan aware. You can edit your question to correct.

Comment: The one in the middle is the one that needs to support vlans. if the edge switches send tags to it, they may be dropped as oversize frames.

Comment: But what about if router is vlan aware too?

Comment: If the middle switch drops the frames, the router will never see them.

Comment: So if the middle switch should be vlan-aware. Can I use below 3 switches vlan unaware? (Considering that each of the 3 switches has only one VLAN)

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In response to

> So if the middle switch should be vlan-aware. Can I use below 3
>   switches vlan unaware? (Considering that each of the 3 switches has
>   only one VLAN)

Yes you can, by configuring the port that connect to the router in trunk mode and the other ports on the central switch in access mode , each in appropriate VLAN.

However I strongly recommend that you go for 4 VLAN aware switches. The additional management capabilities and flexibility it will give you largely compensate the additional cost (which is not so much).